# error on getting dataframe defined in other object i.e. TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable

Tags: python, pandas

i am new to python and trying to create some code for my understanding. i am getting error for getting  `tick_data` in another object.

following is my code where i defined dataframe

```
    class MarketDataLoader():
    
    def __init__(self,symbols,cashPerTrade,broker_config: 'BrokerConfig'):
      self._tick_data = None
      #few other init var

   @property
   def tick_data(self) -> 'pandas.DataFrame':
        return self._tick_data
    
    def process_tick_data(self, data, dataframe):
        # some processing for tick data and assign value to tick data
   
    def process_and_resample_tick_data(self):
        self._api.subscribe_market_data(self._symbols, (self.process_tick_data,))
```

when `process_and_resample_tick_data` method got called it starts streaming to `process_tick_data` method

then in trade executor class

```
class TradeExecutor():

    def __init__(self,market_data: 'MarketDataLoader',trade_config:'TradeConfig',broker_config:'BrokerConfig'):
        print("Init Trade execute")
        self._market_data = market_data
        self._trade_config = trade_config
        self._broker_config =broker_config

    def start_trade(self):
        logger.info("starting trade from Trade Executor for ",self._trade_config.symbols,
                    " cash for trade ",self._trade_config.cash_per_trade)
        while True:  # repeat until we get all historical bars
            time.sleep(10)
            print("trade time ",self._market_data)
#error on following line of code
            tick_frame = self._market_data.tick_data()
```

i am getting error on `tick_frame = self._market_data.tick_data()` i am not sure how to resolve following error

```
tick_frame = self._market_data.tick_data()
TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable
python-BaseException
```

Comment: Remove the `@property` decorator if you want `tick_data()` to be callable, or use `self._market_data.tick_data` instead. https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/python/property-decorator

Comment: thanks, i made a minor typo mistake. appreciate your pointer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to call a method declared as a property.

When we use the `@property` decorator we treat the method as an attribute. For example, suppose we have the following class:

```py
class JBug(object):
    def __init__(self):
        name = 'Junie'

    @property
    def hello(self):
        return "Hello, my name is %s" % name
```

To get the desired behavior we do not call `hello`, but treat it as an attribute:

```
>>> J = JBug()
>>> print(J.hello)
Hello, my name is Junie
```